# How to count items in parent category and its descendants?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: Category and Object. Category can have one or more children.  These children can have their own children.  So, the hierarchy is limitless.  A child can have only one parent.  Parent category is category where parent_id is NULL.  Category has objects (one to many relationship).

Sample data:

**Category table**

```
id   name       parent_id    
1    Sports     NULL
2    Home       NULL
3    Fashion    NULL
4    Cycling    1
5    Football   1
6    Bath       2
7    Bedroom    2
8    Lighting   7
```

Assume that number of objects in category looks like this:

```
name       COUNT(object)   
Sports     5
Home       3
Fashion    4
Cycling    2
Football   3
Bath       2
Bedroom    1
Lighting   3
```

I need to get count of objects only for parent categories including count of objects in their descendants using pure MySql or MySql and PHP.

Here's the result I am looking for.

```
Sports     5 + 2(for Cycling)+3(for Football) = 10
Home       3+2(Bath)+1(Bedroom)+3(Lighting)= 9
Fashion    4
```

I know about nested sets, but can't change current DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

the following php code can solve this problem, May be there is a better answer but that what I have tell now

```
<?php
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
    $stm = $conn->prepare('select tem.id, tem.num, c.name, c.parent_id from category c inner join (SELECT c.id ,count(c.id) as num FROM `category` c left join object o on o.category = c.id 
group by c.id) tem on c.id = tem.id');
    $stm->execute();
    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $temp = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $temp[$row->id] = $row;
    }


    $pre_final = moh($temp);
    $final = array();
    foreach ($pre_final as $row){
            if(!$row->parent_id){
                $final[] = $row;
            }
    }

    print_r($final);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

function moh($arr){
    $flag = true;
    foreach($arr as $row){
        if(!$row->parent_id){

        } else{
            $arr[$row->parent_id]->num += $row->num; 
            $row->num = 0;
        }
    }



    foreach($arr as $row){
        if(!$row->parent_id){

        } else{
            if($row->num != 0){
                $flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if($flag){
        return $arr;
    } else{
        return moh($arr);
    }


}
```